# How do I get the first Monday of a given month in Go?

Tags: time, go

I'm trying to get the first Monday of a given month.

Best way I can come up with is to loop through first seven days and return when `.Weekday() == "Monday"`. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you give us more information?  This is a very general question.  It's pretty hard to understand.  What sort of data structures do you have to use?  Have you stored the months, and # of days in each month?  You really haven't given us much detail and I don't know if anybody is going to jump right in and "do your homework for you."  Post the code that you already have.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By looking at the .Weekday() of the time, you can compute the first Monday.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// FirstMonday returns the day of the first Monday in the given month.
func FirstMonday(year int, month time.Month) int {
    t := time.Date(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    return (8-int(t.Weekday()))%7 + 1
}

func main() {
    for m := 1; m <= 12; m++ {
        fmt.Println(m, FirstMonday(2013, time.Month(m)))
    }
}
```