# How can I make a database structure in mongodb for saving the date range?

Tags: mongodb, go

Here I'm saving the date range using golang. Suppose we have to save the all monday comes between the range of the `1-may-2018` to `14-july-2018`.

How we will find all the monday between these range using **golang** and on the other hand we have set the `start_time` (`8:00 A.M.`) and the `end_time` (`6:00 P.M.`) of the first two coming monday in the database but on the third monday we have a change in the schedule that there is a time change like `start_time` (`9:00 A.M.`) and `end_time` (`5:00 P.M.`). Then how I will make my database to make this situation in practically using the golang.

Can Anybody help me for this to solve this solution. I made a database for and I do ppr work on it and make some fields shown below:-

```
Fields for Schedule //Schedule is a collection name
 Id (int)
 Day (string)
 Start_hours (int)
 Start_minutes (int)
 End_hours (int)
 End_minutes (int)
 Start_date (timestamp)
 End_date (timestamp)
```

How I will select monday between the selected range and how will I do the situation I explained above can anybody give guidance to me to make this situation easier. Thank you if this is a basic question then I'm really sorry.

Comment: This is actually a very broad subject. There's really "a lot" of different ways to approach this, and anyone who even says there's a "best practice" is outright lying. The only thing that really matters here is "how your application uses the data". Unfortunately it's a mantra that needs to be repeated for every question about "what structure do I use for xyz scenario?". So you can use different records, you can use arrays within documents, you can also use document keys within a document for different time intervals. The variations usually come in "how you read" and "how you write".

Comment: Usually though the "general" separation is between "Date" and "Time". So instead of all the different fields, you can probably consider if simply a "Date" and something like "milliseconds since start of day" for each set of "start" and "end" will usually cover most cases. But we really don't know exactly what your application intends to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make something like this.

1. Find the first Monday date from the date range (see for example [How do I get the first Monday of a given month in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122477/how-do-i-get-the-first-monday-of-a-given-month-in-go)
2. Mondays happen every week, so you can easily find the rest of dates by adding 7 days till the end date
3. Store all the Monday dates you found with the start and end times

I wouldn't bother with hours and minutes as you can easily get them from the timestamps in Go. Here is the simplified DB structure I would make

```
Fields for Schedule //Schedule is a collection name
 Id (int) 
 Day (string)
 Date (timestamp) // the actual date
 Start (timestamp)
 End (timestamp)
```

You don't need any more fields. You can get the day of the week (Day (string) in your structure, e.g. Monday) from the Date field too, but I believe if you want to query the collection by different days, this might speed things up, but be careful if you need to adjust for time zones. If you work with more than one, then store everything in UTC and you may have an extra filed Timezone, cos a date could be Monday for one zone and Sunday for another.

So, the Schedule will hold weekdays and start and end times for each of them. I'm not sure if you need to store initial date ranges, the Schedule collection will hold that range as well, form the first record to the last one. In my mind, I'd initially populate the collection with a given date range, then later on, I can modify it by adding new days, or deleting them.
When you query this collection with some start and end date range for the Date field, if your first result comes newer than 7 days from the start, this means you miss 1 or more entries from the start. If the last result comes older than 7 days from the range end, this means you miss some entries prior to the range end.

There is nothing specific to Go, in my opinion, Go works well with dates and you don't need any special date structures in your DB.